# On my SiriKit demo, application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler: method did not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, ios10, sirikit

On my SiriKit demo project, I did handle `INSendMessageIntent` on `MyMessageHandler` object, and implements the methods define by protocol `INSendMessageIntentHandling`, one of that:

```
- (void)handleSendMessage:(INSendMessageIntent *)intent completion:(void (^)(INSendMessageIntentResponse * _Nonnull))completion {
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    NSUserActivity *userActivity = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:NSStringFromClass([INSendMessageIntent class])];
    userActivity.title = NSStringFromClass([INSendMessageIntent class]);
    INSendMessageIntentResponse *response = [[INSendMessageIntentResponse alloc] initWithCode:INSendMessageIntentResponseCodeSuccess userActivity:userActivity];
    completion(response);
}
```

I did set value of `title` property with a string and make sure `userActivity` is not a nil object. and then, I implements method named:`(BOOL)application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:` on `AppDelegate.m` and returned `YES`

And now, the problem is coming:

run the main program, then, debug the Extension program.

the method `(BOOL)application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:` **did not be called**, and i already added the item named:`INSendMessageIntent` for IntentsSupported array on info.plist file in Extension program.

- Xcode 8.2.1

Thanks!

Comment: did you ever solve this? I am running into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the response with `INSendMessageIntentResponseCodeInProgress`